# RabbitMQ cannot bind JMS exchange to queue

Tags: rabbitmq, jms, spring-amqp, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmq-jms

I face an odd issue when I bind an `x-jms-topic` exchange to a queue using the JMS plugin `rabbitmq_jms_topic_exchange` as RabbitMQ is not a JMS provider. I face the issue that neither the UI nor the command line succeeds in creating the binding.

Here are my steps:

1. I use this [docker-compose](https://gist.github.com/sayganov/470c5029f51a5278a9b335f0c087989c) file with no modifications, except I tried two images:

   - `rabbitmq:3-management-alpine` (default)
   - `rabbitmq:3.12.8-management-alpine`
2. Upon starting-up the RabbitMQ instance, I enable the JMS plugin in the Docker container:

   ```bash
   rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_jms_topic_exchange
   ```
3. I create a JMS exchange `jms-exchange` and queue `jms-queue` (either UI or command line)

   ```bash
   rabbitmqadmin declare exchange name=jms-exchange type=x-jms-topic
   ```

   ```bash
   rabbitmqadmin declare queue name=jms-queue durable=false
   ```
4. So far so good, now create a binding (again either UI or commandline) where the routing key has the same name as the queue for the sake of simplicity:

   ```bash
   rabbitmqadmin declare binding source=jms-exchange destination=jms-queue routing_key=jms-queue
   ```
5. The last command gives me an obscure error that says nothing useful, here is what I get both in UI and the command line:

   ```
   *** Request to node rabbit@f823cbcfe081 failed with {'EXIT',
       {function_clause,
        [{erl_scan,string,
          [error,1,[]],
          [{file,"erl_scan.erl"},
           {line,156}]},
         {rabbit_jms_topic_exchange,
          decode_term,1,
          [{file,
            "rabbit_jms_topic_exchange.erl"},
           {line,205}]},
         {rabbit_jms_topic_exchange,
          generate_binding_fun,1,
          [{file,
            "rabbit_jms_topic_exchange.erl"},
           {line,189}]},
         {rabbit_jms_topic_exchange,
          add_binding,3,
          [{file,
            "rabbit_jms_topic_exchange.erl"},
           {line,123}]},
         {rabbit_exchange,
          '-callback0/5-lc$^0/1-0-',
          4,
          [{file,
            "rabbit_exchange.erl"},
           {line,54}]},
         {rabbit_exchange,callback,
          4,
          [{file,
            "rabbit_exchange.erl"},
           {line,49}]},
         {rabbit_binding,add,3,
          [{file,
            "rabbit_binding.erl"},
           {line,133}]},
         {rabbit_channel,
          binding_action,10,
          [{file,
            "rabbit_channel.erl"},
           {line,1863}]}]}}
   ```

I can bind any exchange type (`direct`, `fanout`...) to the queue but not `x-jms-topic`. The following works:

```bash
rabbitmqadmin declare binding source=amq.direct destination=jms-queue routing_key=jms-queue
```

---

What is the issue? Perhaps I misunderstood the role of JMS in RabbitMQ. I intend to connect to the RabbitMQ via the JMS connector using Spring Boot.

- How to configure RabbitMQ + JMS in the minimum form?
- If the exchange (of `x-jms-topic` type) cannot be bound to the queue, what is its role in the JMS concept?